# Octobercms Rename file after upload in media.file.upload event

Tags: octobercms

Currently the media library allows you to upload files that have spaces in them.
I want to prevent this for a number of reasons.
My current plan is to rename the file after it's been uploaded inside the file.media.upload event.

I get the $originalPath through, and an instance of UploadedFile($newPath)

I can get the original file name by using..

```
$newPath->getClientOriginalName();
```

and then sanitize that.

**[Update]**

To rename the file I used the MediaLibrary class' moveFile() method. See updated code below

```
Event::listen('media.file.upload', function($widget, $originalPath, $newPath) {
    if (strpos($originalPath, ' ') !== false) {
        $sanitizedFilePath = str_replace(' ', '-', $originalPath);
        MediaLibrary::instance()->moveFile($originalPath, $sanitizedFilePath);
    }
});

Event::listen('media.file.rename', function($widget, $originalPath, $newPath) {
    if (strpos($newPath, ' ') !== false) {
        $sanitizedFilePath = str_replace(' ', '-', $newPath);
        MediaLibrary::instance()->moveFile($newPath, $sanitizedFilePath);
    }
});

Event::listen('media.folder.create', function($widget, $newFolderPath) {
    if (strpos($newFolderPath, ' ') !== false) {
        $sanitizedFilePath = str_replace(' ', '-', $newFolderPath);
        MediaLibrary::instance()->moveFolder($newFolderPath, $sanitizedFilePath);
    }
});

Event::listen('media.folder.rename', function($widget, $originalPath, $newPath) {
    if (strpos($newPath, ' ') !== false) {
        $sanitizedFilePath = str_replace(' ', '-', $newPath);
        MediaLibrary::instance()->moveFolder($newPath, $sanitizedFilePath);
    }
});
```

The problem I face now is that images uploaded through the richeditor don't return the renamed file, it's still trying to show the file with it's original / uploaded file name.

A temporary solution I've used at the minute is to hide the upload option and disabled pasting images into the editor by extending the Froala options, this makes it so that you're forced into choosing an image through the media library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can do it we just need to rename uploaded file on the disk for this we can use `MediaLibrary`

you used wrong event syntax for `upload`

> Real one is : **Event::listen('media.file.upload', function($widget, $filePath, $uploadedFile) { });** you used syntax for `media.file.rename` they all are same but variable passed to them are different

You can use this code this can `rename` file name once its uploaded to media

```
<?php
use System\Classes\MediaLibrary;
use Event;

// ...

// we listedn for file upload event
Event::listen('media.file.upload', function($widget, $filePath, $uploadedFile) {

    // we get file's original name with spaces may be
    $originalName = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

    // sanitize it and wait for when we can use it
    $sanitizedFileName = str_replace(' ', '-', $originalName);

    // now we need only path where we need to move file 
    // break path in to chunks   
    $filePathChunks = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filePath);

    // this simple logic will remove real file name from last 
    // and add our brand new  $sanitizedFileName yahh ! wait is over
    $filePathChunks[ (count($filePathChunks) - 1) ] = $sanitizedFileName;

    // again join the path
    $newPath = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filePathChunks);


    $isRename = true;
    // and use MediaLibrary function to move file
    MediaLibrary::instance()->moveFile($filePath, $newPath, $isRename);

   // move file it means rename file in linux/unix term so do not get confuse here.
});
```

this code will get job done for you :)

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: I eventually listened for these 4 events - media.file.upload, media.file.rename, media.folder.create, media.folder.rename to try and catch all cases where files / folders could potentially include spaces.

Comment: Thanks Neil, could you show us your code? It's a bit unclear how to listen for 4 events without being redundant.

Comment: @chocolata if you want to listen all 4 without being redundant, just listen all 4 events and call some single function inside it which can handle all events.

Comment: Hi Hardik, I just realized that the code for each event needs to be different, as different actions need to be taken for a rename action. @Neil Carpenter, could you please show us your solution? That would be great.

Comment: then what is issue with your code means if its not redundant then just add code, if you have any issue just post question with code so we can help you. @NeilCarpenter may be away meanwhile we can help you.

Comment: What code would you like to see exactly? I updated my original question to include the code that renames & moves the files & folders. Do you want to see the code that extends the froala settings that hides the upload file functionality?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, Neil, and thank you so much for this! This is very useful and it has multiple use cases! @HardikSatasiya, thank you for your follow-up!